# PHP exec() and custom Python module

Tags: php, python

*** edit ***
After reinstalling the module, everything worked fine.

I have installed a python module on my webserver.

When I do "whereis python" I get following path:

```
python: /usr/bin/python2.4 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python2.4 /usr/include/python2.4 /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

Later when I check my modules path, it was installed here:

```
/usr/llib/python2.4/site-packages/MyModule/myModule
```

Now in my PHP script, I am doing this:

```
exec("python /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/MyModule/myModule script.py -v pixfx.xml 2>&1", $output, $return);
```

This script does not get executed.

Any issues with what I am doing so far?

Thanks

******************* edit ******************

```
#! /usr/bin/env python 
import sys 
import os 
import getopt 
import re 
from fontTools.ttLib import TTFont 
from fontTools.ttLib.tables.otBase import OTLOffsetOverflowError 
from fontTools.ttLib.tables.otTables import fixLookupOverFlows, fixSubTableOverFlows     
from fontTools.misc.macCreatorType import getMacCreatorAndType 
from fontTools import version
```

---

Comment: Do not put things like `SOLVED:` in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should you be doing

```
exec("/usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/MyModule/myModule script.py -v pixfx.xml 2>&1", $output, $return);
```

OR

```
exec("/usr/bin/python/python /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/MyModule/myModule script.py -v pixfx.xml 2>&1", $output, $return);
```

Comment: ok I ran into another bug after I got the exec() to work.

I have the module installed correctly, still I get following error:
************
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/MyModule/myModulw/script.py", line 60, in ?
    from myModule.ttLib import TTFont
    ImportError: No module named myModule.ttLib
**************
Any idea?

Comment: you would have to show the source of `script.py` and it loks like it cant import some fonts, im not that good at Python but if you post your code ill take a look

Comment: The script itself is about generating fonts. Thats why you see things like "TTFont" etc. These are module names :)

Comment: uts not the modules causing the script, its a parser error, witch to fix we need the source code of the .py

Comment: Hi,
THis is how the .py script looks like:
**************** #! /usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
import getopt
import re
from fontTools.ttLib import TTFont
from fontTools.ttLib.tables.otBase import OTLOffsetOverflowError
from fontTools.ttLib.tables.otTables import fixLookupOverFlows, fixSubTableOverFlows
from fontTools.misc.macCreatorType import getMacCreatorAndType
from fontTools import version
************************************ I have removed all the comments.... so the line 60 is "from fontTools.ttLib import TTFont"

Comment: to add to my previous comment: TTFont is a "class" defined in a file called __init__.py inside a folder called "ttLib" which is again inside a folder called "fontTools".

Comment: that was supposed to be two underscores before and after 'init' :)

Comment: can you append it to your OP please and wrap it in some code tags

Comment: are you sure that 'fontTools.ttLib' contains the module 'TTFont' ? the  library seems to exists but within the library the module is failing, try re downloading the module.

Comment: yes TTFont is a class defined inside a python file called (doubleunderscore)init(doubleunderscore).py............ this file resides inside a folder called ttLib, which is inside a foler called fontTools (where my python script is).

Comment: your best bet is to make a new Post and ask specifically about this issue, i understand the structure of pythen but thats as far as i go, sorry mate.

Comment: I just did help('modules') in SSH and the list returned does not contain FontTools.... how come? Does it mean the module is not installed and it is just residing in site-packages?

Comment: i would think so, http://docs.python.org/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.command.register

Answer (score 0):

You might find it useful to debug under the user that php is running under, ie www-data, apache, etc. This is helpful for uncovering any permission, path or environment issues that may arise.