# Python (sympy) string to php issues

Tags: php, python

I have a weird situation.  I am calling a python program from my webpage (written in PHP). It normally works fine, but I when I add

```
import sympy
```

I get problems (this one line is the only difference).

Basically, when I run the program from the terminal (with 'import sympy') it works just fine (prints 6 strings), but when I call the program from my php file it returns an empty array (instead of an array with 6 strings like it should).  The two commands are

terminal:

```
python MyProgram.py arg1
```

from php:

```
$command='python MyProgram.py arg1';
exec($command, $output);
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure it's running? do you get a return value if you have `exec($command, $output, $return_value)`?

Comment: The $return_value is 1...so it runs but there is a general error, correct?

Comment: yes. make sure that python is in the path of whatever shell php's using when it does the exec() stuff (or use an /absolute/path/to/python), and that your .py program is in the same working directory as the php script's.

Comment: I see what you mean, I think the problem is something along [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548919/solved-php-exec-problem-with-custom-python-module) lines.